# IpOverUsbSvc exception as I am deploying my App to the phone

Tags: exception, windows-services, windows-phone

I am developing Windows Phone app and from time to time I am getting this exception as I am trying to run the app on my device:

> Error     Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot
>   be found. Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (`IpOverUsbSvc`) is not
>   running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport
>   (`IpOverUsbSvc`) from the services management console.

I know that I can start the service from the `services.msc`, but why this service going down periodicly? Can I configure it to run always?

Answer (score 0):

you should try these solutions.

1. Restart "Windows phone IP over USB  Transport" service(in local services)
          OR
2. Un-install all USB controllers and restart the computer(it will automatically re-install all USB controllers) in Device manager
   OR
3. If you have registered more than one phones to your Microsoft/windows development account. than remove your present phone from account and rename it to the another registered phone name.(this worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

I come here to bring solution that u might like I suggest you to try open service menu on your OS Windows here's the screnshot

on the form try to search Windows phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)then u should right click and Start it then you may deploy your apps and see whether this solution works or no.